# How to delete image uploaded to cloudinary in node js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, cloudinary

I'm finding it difficult to delete uploaded images in my cloudinary account. When I delete a particular post only the post gets deleted from database but in my cloudinary account the image still remains there. I want to know how to delete both post and images in my cloudinary account together.

Comment: Can you provide an example of an image that you didn't manage to delete? Can you share a snippet of how are you performing deletions at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`destroy`](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#syntax-1) method

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(public_id, options, callback);
```

or, use the [`delete_resources`](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#delete_resources) method

```
cloudinary.v2.api.delete_resources(public_ids, options, callback);
```

Comment: I'm getting error result that public_id is not defined

Comment: That is just a placeholder, you need to have a variable that stores the `public_id` like `const public_id = 'someimagename.jpg';` @Gabriel

Comment: @gabriel Keep in mind that the value public_id should be the filename preceded with its path in Cloudinary, e.g - "folder/sub-folder/image-name".